# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode

I designed my chatview controller at the beginning. However, I made some change later on which is I deleted the cell in the Chat View Controller.  I run the code and it throws me an error " terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" . How would I fix this problem? [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLiea.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUC1j.png)

Comment: Can you show us the code which you have implemented ?

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh i just posted the code. Thanks

Comment: please add the reason for the error, Copy the whole error and add and also Keep a breakpoint exception to your code, So that you can easily find what's is the issue, your facing !

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any outlet connected from Storyboard... remove all outlets and actions of deleted ViewControllerClass.swift

Comment: I did not delete any view controller. I just modified my ChatView Controller, I did remove the cell under the table view and it throws me error

Comment: did you create any outlets associated with cell?

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the UI Item that is throwing the error (To find which item is throwing the error, go to appDelegate.swift, then click on the red error.) After you have right-clicked on the item that is throwing the error, scroll down the list. Click the 'x' button on all of the connections, then reconnect them from the ViewController.swift. I have tried this, and it works in at least swift 5. It is possible that this occurred because you deleted an outlet or action.